# Jade - which behaviour for an events loop?

Tags: java, agents-jade

I'm implementing a Multi-Agent System in JADE. Events are placed in a queue and will sequentially happen. An EventManager agent should go through the queue and handle them one by one.

So my EventManager should take the first event - send out messages to the other agents, whom will "solve" the event. 
**After** the first event has been completely solved should the second event be taken and solved. (etc. for many more events)

My problem thus is which behaviour to use to implement this?

I thought about a `sequential behaviour` but that uses multiple behaviours sequentially while this is one behaviour (grabbing the event and solving it) multiple times, but only after the previous one has been done.

I like the idea of the `generic behaviour` but instead of the switch a for loop. Unfortunately it is absolute necessary that the previous event is completely solved before the next one is opened.

How to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

One important thing is here, how the communication between agents is orgainzed?

Do you get answers from all agents when they did their work? This can be archived by using communication protocols like ContractNet or something more handy.

If you have received all answers, you can start a new 'job' behaviour (can be an OneShotBehaviour for example), wait for agent answers again and finally, decide if to start a new job or terminate.